# Configurable products and wholesale price

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, group-price

I have configurable product and also it contains bunch of simple products.
For all simple products there are 2 types of group price.
1). Retailer 
2). Wholesale

Above is working fine whenever any wholesaler login at front end. they can see their wholesale price.

But i don't know why this is not working with configurable products.

Any ideas ??
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: 1- Check your configurable product's tier price.
2- Check your magento version. There was a problem about configurable prices at 1.9.x.x
3- Check your other storeviews.